# How to generate css by database in asp.net..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change the content of style sheet dynamically like:

```
 .menu
{
 color: #333333;
 Font-size : 12px;
}
```

I want to change the color and font size dynamically. 
How to replace value of color (like #333333 to #ffffff) and font size (12px to 14px) dynamically.

I am finding the way to use variables in stylesheet, and assigning it to attributes that can make my work easy.

Waiting for reply with example.

Comment: Can you Provide your HTML?

Comment: Write your CSS template, write a ASHX handler, and serve the CSS on demand with your database values in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use asp.net, use inline html. Read [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)

```
<div style="font-size: <% Response.Write(i)%>">
        Hello World<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use JavaSctipt with JQuery:

```
$("#myButton").Click(function()
{
    $(".menu").css({"color":"#ffffff","font-size":"14px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty much sure that you can use variables in stylesheets, what I think a way around for it is to generate the style sheet at run time and assign it to the page.

In you asp.net page you can have like:

```
<head>
    <title>WebForm1</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1">
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#">
    <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript">
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
    <asp:literal id="literalCss" runat="server"></asp:literal>
</head>
```

and than in your code behind you can use:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// create css file here for the specific user and save it in a folder,
// give a meaning full name to file, if user specific you can append user id in name like
string fileName = "cssFile_" + userid + ".css";
    literalCss.Text = @"<link href='/style/" + fileName + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";
}
```

I hope it can help you out.

Comment: You shall make a check as well that if a file is already created of this user than don't create it again.